# Concatenating videos with MoviePy - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int'

Tags: python, typeerror, moviepy

Hi I want to make a method to make a vertical video
I have problem with this line:
text_overlay = mp.concatenate_videoclips(text_clips, method='compose')
I do not know where is problem, but I have that it is in this file:
my code:

```
print("Start")
def create_vertical_video(image_file, music_file, quote):
  ###########

    # Create text clip for each line
    text_clips = []
    for line in lines:
        text_clip = mp.TextClip(line, fontsize=24, color='white', bg_color='black')
        text_clip = text_clip.set_pos('center').set_duration(image.duration)
        text_clips.append(text_clip)

    # Overlay text clips on image
    text_overlay = mp.concatenate_videoclips(text_clips, method='compose')
    final_clip = mp.CompositeVideoClip([image, text_overlay])

    # Add music to final clip
    final_clip = final_clip.set_audio(music)

    # Save video
    final_clip.write_videofile("vertical_video.mp4", fps=24)


create_vertical_video("nature.jpg","music.mp3","Don't be pushed around by the fears in your mind. Be led by the dreams in your heart.")
```

error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
 File "c:\Users\Lukas\Dokumenty\python_scripts\Billionare livestyle\main.py", line 43, in <module>
    create_vertical_video("nature.jpg","music.mp3","Don't be pushed around by the fears in your mind. Be led by the dreams in your heart.")
  File "c:\Users\Lukas\Dokumenty\python_scripts\Billionare livestyle\main.py", line 33, in create_vertical_video
    text_overlay = mp.concatenate_videoclips(text_clips, method='compose')
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\Dokumenty\python_scripts\Billionare livestyle\env\youtube\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\compositing\concatenate.py", line 71, in concatenate_videoclips
    tt = np.cumsum([0] + [c.duration for c in clips])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in cumsum
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\Dokumenty\python_scripts\Billionare livestyle\env\youtube\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2571, in cumsum
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'cumsum', axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out)
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\Dokumenty\python_scripts\Billionare livestyle\env\youtube\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 54, in _wrapfunc
    return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Lukas\Dokumenty\python_scripts\Billionare livestyle\env\youtube\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 43, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
```

Comment: Please include the traceback where the error happens & at best also reduce your code only to the essential parts around this error -> better chance that you will get an answer.